# Pass context when serializing queryset in django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to serialize a queryset using DjangoSerializer but one of a SerializerMethodField requires user instance. So how can I pass user instance in a context?

```
projects = Project.objects.all().order_by('name')
serializer = ProjectSerializer(projects, context={'request': request}, many=True)
```

You can assume that request has user in it.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your context with:

```
context={'user': request.user}
```

or inside your `SerializerMethodField`, use request from `self.context`:

```
self.context['request'].user
```

Comment: I'm already doing this. but then also I'm not receiving context in the serializer.

Comment: Can you share your serializer code? And point out where it is not working?